# Expresiones regulares condicionales en base a un carácter

Tags: regex

¿Es posible crear expresiones regulares en base a caracteres de la cadena?

Me explico con un ejemplo, estoy buscando una expresión regular que valide que en una cadena, si el primer dígito es 0, el segundo no pueda serlo. Pero el resto de dígitos si puedan ser el numero que quieran, ejemplos:

```
0102 - Bien
0123 - Bien
0012 - Mal
```

Pero, que por el contrario, si la cadena empieza por un numero distinto a 0, ese segundo dígito si pueda ser 0 o el número que quiera, ejemplos:

```
1234 - Bien
1000 - Bien
1089 - Bien
```

A ver si me podéis echar una mano con la validación en base a un dígito, por que no termino de dar con la tecla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(0[1-9]\d+|[1-9]\d+)$
  ~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~
   1er grupo  2º grupo
```

Con esto creamos dos posibles grupos de matcheo:

- El primero controla que los números que empiecen por 0 no puedan tener un 0 en el segundo dígito.
- El segundo grupo, que valida cualquier número que **no** empiece por 0, admite cualquier dígito como segunda cifra.

Claro que esta expresión regular podría simplificarse:

```
^0?[1-9]\d+$
```

De tal forma que empezar por `0` es opcional, pero si lo hace, la segunda cifra no podrá ser un `0`, puesto que el grupo `[1-9]` no lo permite

> Necesitaría que la expresión empezase a "actuar" desde el primer carácter, no que necesite 3

```
^(0(?:[1-9]\d*)?|[1-9]\d*)$
```

`(?:..)` Permite crear grupo pero sin capturarlo. la idea es que todo lo que no sea el `0` inicial sea optativo (por eso tras este grupo de no captura hay una interrogación: `(?:..)?`. Además se han reemplazado los `+` por `*` para que coincida con 0 o más apariciones en vez de con necesariamente una.

Esta expresión, al igual que la primera, puede simplificarse facilmente:

```
^0?(?:[1-9]\d*)?$
```

Comment: Genial, voy a probarlo, lo que no entiendo, es, ¿pq cuando solo escribo un 0, me pone que no es valida la expresión y luego ya si que va detectando?

Comment: @Diego la expresión regular que te he puesto espera un mínimo de 3 dígitos: El 0, un dígito del 1 al 9 y un tercer dígito... o dos dígitos (uno del 1 al 9 más un segundo dígito)

Comment: Vale. Esa misma expresión, podría empezar a validarse desde el primer elemento?

Comment: @Diego no te entiendo

Comment: Necesitaría que la expresión empezase a "actuar" desde el primer carácter, no que necesite 3. Dado que si escribo 0, no tiene que ser un "error", estoy empezando a plantearme que quizás no sea lo correcto el usar una expresión regular.

Comment: @Diego las expresiones regulares sirven justamente para esto, para validar patrones.

Comment: Gracias por todo lo que te has molestado @eferion marco la respuesta como buena, dado que así es, aunque a mi no me haya resultado válida finalmente.

Comment: @Diego ¿Por qué razón no es válida? La última modificación acepta el 0...

Comment: Pues no te puedo aportar mas que un SyntaxError en el xaml, llevo un buen rato dándole vueltas, pero no veo el que puede pasar.

Comment: @Diego no será que las barras invertidas tienes que ponerlas dobles? La barra invertida se usa como caracter de escape en muchos contextos

Comment: Es lo primero que he pensado, pero con esta funciona bien ^0?[1..9]\d+$

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106374/discussion-between-eferion-and-diego).

Answer (score 1):

En base a los comentarios se desprende lo siguiente:

1. El numero 0 aislado es una solución, la expresión sería: `^0$`
2. En el caso que el 0 aparezca, obligatoriamente deberá ser seguido
   por un digito del rango del 1 al 9, en caso de haber mas de 2
   dígitos estos serán todos numéricos pudiendo aparecer cero o más
   veces, la expresión sería: `^0?[1-9]\d*$`

Agrupándo los 2 casos tendríamos: `^(0|0?[1-9]\d*)$`

**Nota Importante**: Si lo que se esta evaluando es una cadena que contiene internamente los patrones a ubicar, por ejemplo: 0 00 0102 0123 0012 03 Casa 120 Puerta 2516 Caracas

En este caso se delimita por bloques de palabras quedando la expresión regular: `\b(0|0?[1-9]\d*)\b`

Recordar agregar los parámetros global y multi-línea en caso de que la cadena tenga varias líneas.

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo tu pregunta de forma literal, la respuesta es más sencilla de lo que parece:

```
^00
```

Eso es todo. Si coincide con `^00`, entonces está mal, si no coincide, está bien. Sólo es cuestión de negar el resultado final del regex.

Claro que si además te interesa validar que efectivamente sea un número, iría con [la respuesta de linuxexp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/456195/193460) que lo resuelve.